# Reset Trove house/cornerstone

Tags: trove

Is there any command I can use to reset my [Cornerstone](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Cornerstone)?

I want to make a lot of layout change on it, including undo the dig i've made to create a -1 floor. It would be nice if i could remove the items i want to keep, and "reset" the state of the Cornerstone to start fresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/clearcornerstone - Resets your cornerstone back to flat land. Everything on your cornerstone will be deleted after the player confirms the clear.

**NOTE** All blocks will be lost. Salvage what you want and confirm its in your bag before you clear.

**Reference:**

- [Trove Commands](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Commands)

Comment: Good catch. And, found the reference to your answer here - http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Commands

Comment: Oh wow, any clue when this got added?

Answer (score 1):

For now it is not possible to reset your cornerstone. It really is a pain. The game still is expanding though, and new things are being added regularly. I'm pretty sure we'll see some improvements for cornerstone building someday.

Right now you could use bombs to remove large parts of it, but you might damage the things you want to keep.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first idea. And i will also have to fulfill the hole of the Floor -1 of my house :P

Answer (score 0):

Since last [big patch](http://forums.trovegame.com/showthread.php?87055-Multiple-Cornerstone-Edition-7AM-PST-3PM-GMT-1-5-2016&s=b982d6eb26240d1e74ea8b9e3b44e86b) you are able to have multiple cornerstones(if you unlock more slots) between which u swap via F1 - Cornerstones. It also allows you to reset the cornerstone state.